# mysql query joining three queries into sigle query

Tags: mysql, join

Please help on this query, here is sql fiddler : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8acc1/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, v.sel_category,c.curr_tittle , c.curr_desc, v.videos_desc 
FROM  wp_curriculum c, wp_career_vidoes v 
WHERE c.id IN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT curr_id 
    FROM wp_curriculum_category 
    WHERE curr_category IN (2,3)) AS I 

AND I.curr_category = v.sel_category 
GROUP BY I.curr_category
```

Comment: This won't work, since "I" is already a column:
 WHERE I.curr_category = v.sel_category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean this?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT c.id, 
        v.sel_category,
        c.curr_tittle , 
        c.curr_desc, 
        v.videos_desc 
FROM    wp_curriculum c
        INNER JOIN wp_curriculum_category cat
            ON c.id = cat.curr_id
        INNER JOIN wp_career_vidoes v
            ON v.sel_category  = cat.curr_category
WHERE   cat.curr_category IN (2,3)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8acc1/19)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)